# Error: Request error while attempting to reach https://uzvct2zv.api.sanity.io/v2023-10-01/data/query/production

Tags: sanity

I have a Next.js 13 website that is using sanity.io CMS.

Recently, whenever I make a build using `npm run build`, I receive lots of errors that look like this one.  I tried to debug, but with no luck.

```
Error: Request error while attempting to reach https://uzvct2zv.api.sanity.io/v2023-10-01/data/query/production?query=%0A*%5B_type%3D%3D%27siteSettings%27+%26%26+locale%3D%3D%24locale+%26%26+%21%28_id+in+path%28%27drafts.**%27%29%29%5D%5B0%5D+%7B%0A++navBar+%7B%0A++++darkLogo+%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3A+asset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++lightLogo+%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3A+asset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++links%5B%5D%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++pathname%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++languageLink%7B%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++locale%2C%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%2C%0A++footer%7B%0A++++slogan%2C%0A++++about%2C%0A++++copyright%2C%0A++++columns%5B%5D%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++links%5Benabled%3D%3Dtrue%5D%7B%0A++++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++++title%2C%0A++++++++pathname%2C%0A++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++socialLinks%5Benabled%3D%3Dtrue%5D%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++url%2C%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++logo%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3Aasset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++appStoreImage%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3Aasset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++playStoreImage%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3Aasset._ref%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%2C%0A++cookiesConsent+%7B%0A++++description%5B%5D+%7B%0A++++++++...%2C%0A++++++++markDefs%5B%5D+%7B%0A++++++++++...%2C%0A++++++++++_type+%3D%3D+%22internalLink%22+%3D%3E+%7B%0A++++++++++++...%2C%0A++++++++++++%22pathname%22%3A+%40.item-%3Eseo.pathname%0A++++++++++%7D%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++accept%2C%0A++++decline%0A++%7D%0A%7D&%24locale=%22ar%22
    at m.onerror (/Users/aimnblbol/Developer/oolfa-project/oolfa_backend/oolfa_web/.next/server/chunks/8193.js:1:233730)
    at /Users/aimnblbol/Developer/oolfa-project/oolfa_backend/oolfa_web/.next/server/chunks/8193.js:1:233114 {
  isNetworkError: true,
  request: {
    timeout: { connect: 300000, socket: 300000 },
    maxRedirects: 0,
    method: 'GET',
    uri: '/data/query/production?query=%0A*%5B_type%3D%3D%27siteSettings%27+%26%26+locale%3D%3D%24locale+%26%26+%21%28_id+in+path%28%27drafts.**%27%29%29%5D%5B0%5D+%7B%0A++navBar+%7B%0A++++darkLogo+%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3A+asset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++lightLogo+%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3A+asset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++links%5B%5D%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++pathname%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++languageLink%7B%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++locale%2C%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%2C%0A++footer%7B%0A++++slogan%2C%0A++++about%2C%0A++++copyright%2C%0A++++columns%5B%5D%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++links%5Benabled%3D%3Dtrue%5D%7B%0A++++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++++title%2C%0A++++++++pathname%2C%0A++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++socialLinks%5Benabled%3D%3Dtrue%5D%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++url%2C%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++logo%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3Aasset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++appStoreImage%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3Aasset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++playStoreImage%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3Aasset._ref%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%2C%0A++cookiesConsent+%7B%0A++++description%5B%5D+%7B%0A++++++++...%2C%0A++++++++markDefs%5B%5D+%7B%0A++++++++++...%2C%0A++++++++++_type+%3D%3D+%22internalLink%22+%3D%3E+%7B%0A++++++++++++...%2C%0A++++++++++++%22pathname%22%3A+%40.item-%3Eseo.pathname%0A++++++++++%7D%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++accept%2C%0A++++decline%0A++%7D%0A%7D&%24locale=%22ar%22',
    json: true,
    body: undefined,
    query: false,
    headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
    token: undefined,
    tag: undefined,
    perspective: undefined,
    resultSourceMap: undefined,
    canUseCdn: true,
    signal: undefined,
    fetch: { cache: 'force-cache', next: [Object] },
    useAbortSignal: false,
    url: 'https://uzvct2zv.api.sanity.io/v2023-10-01/data/query/production?query=%0A*%5B_type%3D%3D%27siteSettings%27+%26%26+locale%3D%3D%24locale+%26%26+%21%28_id+in+path%28%27drafts.**%27%29%29%5D%5B0%5D+%7B%0A++navBar+%7B%0A++++darkLogo+%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3A+asset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++lightLogo+%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3A+asset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++links%5B%5D%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++pathname%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++languageLink%7B%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++locale%2C%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%2C%0A++footer%7B%0A++++slogan%2C%0A++++about%2C%0A++++copyright%2C%0A++++columns%5B%5D%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++links%5Benabled%3D%3Dtrue%5D%7B%0A++++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++++title%2C%0A++++++++pathname%2C%0A++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++socialLinks%5Benabled%3D%3Dtrue%5D%7B%0A++++++%22id%22%3A_key%2C%0A++++++title%2C%0A++++++url%2C%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++logo%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3Aasset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++appStoreImage%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3Aasset._ref%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++playStoreImage%7B%0A++++++alt%2C%0A++++++%22url%22%3Aasset._ref%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%2C%0A++cookiesConsent+%7B%0A++++description%5B%5D+%7B%0A++++++++...%2C%0A++++++++markDefs%5B%5D+%7B%0A++++++++++...%2C%0A++++++++++_type+%3D%3D+%22internalLink%22+%3D%3E+%7B%0A++++++++++++...%2C%0A++++++++++++%22pathname%22%3A+%40.item-%3Eseo.pathname%0A++++++++++%7D%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%2C%0A++++accept%2C%0A++++decline%0A++%7D%0A%7D&%24locale=%22ar%22',
    proxy: undefined,
    withCredentials: false,
    attemptNumber: 5
  }
}
```

Any idea what it could be? When I copy the URL and place it into sanity Vision, the query returns data without any issues.

Comment: Hi Aimn. Does downgrading Next.js to version `13.5.3` resolve the issue? [There's a GitHub issue you can follow here](https://github.com/sanity-io/next-sanity/issues/664).